# Приведение decimal к нормальному виду

Tags: php, sql

Храню в БД кол-во биткоинов в decimal(15,15)

```
0.004266246300000
0.012133123100000
0.032133123104230
```

Вывожу в шаблон следующим образом:

```
echo ..::getMoney($money);
```

Где getMoney:

```
static public function getMoney($money)
{
    return (float)$money;
}
```

И всё бы ничего, но при слишком маленьком значении, вроде `0.00000000000020` в выводе получаю `2.0E-10`, а использовать просто `echo $money` неудобно, т.к. мешаются нули в конце, подскажите, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: какой результат вы хотите получить, что в вашем понимание нормальный вид?

Comment: для 0.012133123100000 результат 0.0121331231

Comment: а для 0.00000000000020 какой?

Comment: 0.0000000000002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете настроить функцию **number_format()** так как вам нужно.
Я считаю, что это поможет. Полное описание в мануале

Узнаём кол-во символов, после запятой так:

```
$price = '0.004266246300000';
$arrPrice = explode('.', $price);
$symbolSum = iconv_strlen($arrPrice[1]);
```

С удаление нулей из конца строки так:

```
$price = '0.004266246300000';
$price = rtrim($price, '0');
$arrPrice = explode('.', $price);
$symbolSum = iconv_strlen($arrPrice[1]);
```

И дальше можете воспользоваться функцией number_format()

Comment: number_format($number, 3) имеете ввиду? Но как я узнаю, 3 мне нужно или 10 знаков после запятой?

Comment: Вы любопытно прочитайте, как эта функция может работать, вам не нужно будет знать сколько знаков после запятой, вы можете просто разделить их по группам например. Если так уж хочется знать количество символов, после запятой, пример напишу выше